# How to find the reference when key to the find(Object.Class, {CompositeKey}) method is a composite key?

Tags: java, jpa, find, entitymanager, composite-key

How to find a reference when we have composite key(two or more columns) to pass on as second parameter to the JPA entityManager.find(Object.class, compositeKey)?

**My try-**
I have created an **Arraylist** and added the values forming compositeKey it and then passing this list to the **find** method.

For ex: In my situation, **userid** and **projectid** together is the key for the UserProject table and these two have been added to the arraylist named as list, which will be passed as a second parameter to the entityManager find method as shown below:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(userProjectDO.getUserid());
        list.add(userProjectDO.getProjectid());

        UserProject userProject = em.find(UserProject.class,list);
```

But this always return as null, even though userid and projectId exists on the table. Has anyone been into similar issue? Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA's [**EntityManager#find**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) doesn't accept arrays as key but `Object`. Since you are talking about composite key you should implement your key in a separate class which will represent the composite key by listing all the key separate properties. You can achieve this using [EmbeddedId](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) for instance.

For example:

You should define the composite key class and annotate with `@Embeddable`:

```
public class UserProjectKey implements Serializable{
    private String userId;
    private String projectId;

    //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

and use it as `@EmbeddedId` in your entity.

To search by the key you can do:

```
UserProjectKey key = new UserProjectKey("userIdExample", "projectIdExample");
em.find(UserProject.class, key);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach i.e. writing namedQuery to search the table. Posting the implementation just in case it helps anyone.

```
final Query query = em.createNamedQuery("UserProject.findByAll");
```

UserProject Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userproject", schema = "public")

@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "UserProject.findByAll", query = "SELECT a FROM UserProject a where a.userid = :userid and a.projectid = :projectid"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "UserProject.findByUserId", query = "SELECT a FROM UserProject a where a.userid = :userid"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "UserProject.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM UserProject a where a.id = :id" )})
public class UserProject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Integer userid;

    @Column(name = "projectid")
    private Integer projectid;

    @Column(name = "created")
    private Timestamp created;

    @Column(name = "modified")
    private Timestamp modified;

    @Column(name = "modifiedbyid")
    private Integer modifiedbyid;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(final Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }


    public void setProjectid(final Integer projectid) {
        this.projectid = projectid;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(final Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Timestamp getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(final Timestamp modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public Integer getModifiedbyid() {
        return modifiedbyid;
    }

    public void setModifiedbyid(final Integer modifiedbyid) {
        this.modifiedbyid = modifiedbyid;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(final String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

And finally set the query parameters i.e. compositeKey values(userid,projectid) as :

```
final Query query = em.createNamedQuery("UserProject.findByAll");
        query.setParameter("userid",userProjectDO.getUserid());
        query.setParameter("projectid",userProjectDO.getProjectid());
        List<UserProject> userProjectList = query.getResultList();
```

**userProjectList** would contain the row which matches the compositeKey (userId,projectId)

One advantage I see with this approach is that I can write N number of named queries inside the entity class as per the need/requirement. For ex: If we need to work on a view created out of this table. It can be easily achieved by first creating the view and then write another named query to work on it.